# Difference between からすると and にしたら

Tags: grammar

I'm sorry if this sounds like a naive question, but I tend to get confused にしたら and からすると.  Someone said that they are completely [different](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/18360) but to me they seem to both translate to "from the perspective of" as in the following sentences.

> **親からすると、子供はいくつになっても子供で、心配なものだ。**
>   From the point of view of parents, their children regardless of their age are children, and will be their concern. (Feel free to edit the translation.)
>
> **あの人にしたら、私達の親切はかえって迷惑かもしれない**。
>   To that person / From the point of view of that person, our kindness was (considered as) a bother.

Has anyone been through this confusion before? What then is the difference between the two?

Comment: Would you say they mean similar things in the examples in the linked question?

Comment: Oh right, they are really different, least in the linked sentences: the にしたら is used as にする > -たら, which is not the same grammar point that the OP meant.

That said, にしたら can also carry the meaning "from the perspective of," right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That said, にしたら can also carry the meaning "from the perspective of," right?

Yes.
So in the case you provided, にしたら and からすると have the same meaning.

But each of them has other various meanings.
Or more like, they both consist of multiple words(単語) which have various meanings.

からすると = から+する+と
にしたら = に+する+たら

Then mfuji, who answered the op, couldn't come up with the meaning they share, "from the perspective of."
That's why they said "completely different."
It's difficult to identify the meaning of the phrase from multiple ones when no example sentence or context is provided.